# Is there an algorithm similar to Stoer–Wagner algorithm mincut algorithm?

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm

Suppose I want to find the minimum weight cut in a weighted undirected graph. I see Stoer–Wagner algorithm mincut algorithm does help to find the minimum cut. Is there an algorithm similar to Stoer–Wagner mincut algorithm? By similar I mean, same output but using a different procedure.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut.  If that doesn't satisfy, consider asking on the CStheory site instead: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @StephenC Okay I will ask the question to cstheory. Thanks.